# Image Loading in Device context of SDI(MFC VC++)

Tags: mfc, sdi

How to load Images from disk to Device context of and SDI MFC application. I want to choose images from existing folder at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably the easiest to use CImage, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwea7by5(v=vs.80).aspx

It's something like:

```
void CMyDlg::OnBnClickedOpenImage()
{
    CFileDialog dialog(TRUE, NULL, NULL,
        OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST | OFN_HIDEREADONLY,
        L"Windows Bitmap (*.bmp)|*.bmp|JPEG Compressed Image (*.jpg;*.jpeg)|*.jpg; *.jpeg|PNG Image (*.png)|*.png|All Images (*.bmp;*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png)|*.bmp; *.jpg; *.jpeg; *.png|All Files (*.*)|*.*||");

    if (dialog.DoModal() == IDOK)
    {
        HDC hDC = pDC->GetSafeHdc();
        CImage image;
        image.Load(dialog.GetPathName());
        image.Draw(hDC, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

**Edit:** Added the open file dialog.

Comment: I know i can load image like that, but i want to choose from folder ,when press open button it should open a dirctory ,from there i want to choose any image.

Comment: I hope I understand it correctly now. I updated the answer, which is the event handler of the OnClick of your "Open" button.

Comment: How i will get pDC intialized ,when i am adding this code,it is showing debug assertion faild error

Comment: You're talking about a "Device context", I guess you refer to some paint method? Then the easiest way is probably to store the CImage as a member variable of the SDI document/window class and use that in the paint method where you have your DC.